# Why does Gangs of Wasseypur have some seemingly absurdist scenes?

Tags: indian-cinema, gangs-of-wasseypur

In *Gangs of Wasseypur*, there is a [poetry recital](https://youtu.be/xndCrKr3ha0?t=1492), the lyrics of which are quite unrelated to the story. It is about a river flowing through mountains playing along the way with the rocky terrain. It may be argued that there is a metaphor with the life of the protagonist, however the words don't feel related to the story at that point to a native speaker.

More importantly, all the characters in the 8 second scene are only confined to the scene with no backward and forward story lines. The sets are also created for that one scene, with no further usage.

There are many such seemingly absurdist scenes in the film. [Another one is here](https://youtu.be/dz3uCM-MrGY?t=8052) (this one is in English): Absolutely unrelated lyrics and characters in the scene.

1. What is the intention behind such scenes?
2. Are such scenes also known in other films?

P. S. These songs are in the absurdist genre, quite unlike almost all other Bollywood songs, which though being unnecessary sometimes, at least relate to the story and use the characters in the film. The songs in the question are absolutely unrelated to the story, and use irrelevant characters and sets.

My use of "absurd" here is not in the sense of unnecessary or futile; more in the sense of **unexplainable, incongruent, and strange.** *They are not even good songs*: forgettable lyrics with amateur music and singers. A kind of [Dadaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dada)?

Comment: Can't this be a tribute to [Bollywood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi_cinema) style?

Comment: @OldPadawan Thank you for your comment. Edited the question adding more details.